# WSO2 Proxy: Catch exceptions thrown during runtime?

Tags: proxy, wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to catch exceptions thrown during runtime in WSO2 Proxy? My proxy service throws a great deal of exception (in each iteration) and they tend to create much overhead for the ESB which runs short of memory. I would like to catch/suppress these exceptions and let the proxy run to its end after displaying a single error message for each exception.

Comment: Have you tried using a sequence referred like this in the target which does a makefault? `<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="error" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
    <target faultSequence="nameoffaultseq">`

Comment: I have used a faultsequence in the proxy which do not seem to catch any exceptions. But have not included the target tag. Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using makefault as explained [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Fault+Mediator)

In your proxy under target you can set faultsequence to point to a sequence defined separately as

Now nameoffaultseq will have code like this , this is supposed to catch runtime exceptions and does for me.

`<makefault xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" version="soap11">
   <code xmlns:soap11Env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" value="soap11Env:VersionMismatch" />
   <reason value="test message " />
   <role></role>
</makefault>`

This is for soap11 response

for non soap like rest you can use something like

```
<makefault version="pox">
    <reason expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>

</makefault>
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
       <Error>
          <ErrorCode>$1</ErrorCode>
                                <ErrorDesc>$2</ErrorDesc>
                                <ErrorSource>$3</ErrorSource>
                                <ErrorType>SE</ErrorType>
      </Error>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_EXCEPTION')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="500" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
<property name="messageType" expression="get-property('AcceptFromConsumer')" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>`
```

Where the arguments are standard error properties provided by wso2esb , so in general for runtime exceptions this should be sufficient. More details on error handling are [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Error+Handling)